# Angularjs: How to reference controller from within directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, communication

I have looked over many questions and blogs about "communicating between directives and controllers". Most of them really confuse me, and I cannot tell if they apply to me at all.

I want:

```
   - to keep ng-controller in my html 
   - to avoid putting everything on $scope (ie. to use "controller as")
   - to prevent my controller from firing twice 
   - to send a method of a local-scope controller 
          to a method of another-scope controller.
```

I have gotten it to work *if I include a reference to the local-scope controller within the directive*. But then it forces that controller **to be instantiated twice**.

So how to cleanly get a directive that is in the same local-scope as a controller to reference a method within that controller?

SEE my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dAXg3Dl2WdNMMNQA1mtA)

```
<head>
  <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    angular.module( "my_app" , [] )
      .controller( "A_controller" , 
                   function( $scope )
                     { $scope.A_method = function( argf )  
                                           { argf.apply( null) ;      
                                           } ;
                    }
                  )
      .controller( "B_controller" , 
                   function( $scope )
                     { console.log( "B initiated" ) ; 
                       // FIRES TWICE if directive includes 'controller:"B_controller"'

                       var B_this = this ;     

                       //$scope.B_method = function() { alert( "GOAL" ) ;  } ; 
                         B_this.B_method = function() { alert( "GOAL" ) ;  } ; 
                     } 
                 )
      .directive( "bDirective" , 
                  function()
                     { return {
                                controller : "B_controller" ,
                                link : function( scope , element , atts , ctrl )  
                                         {
                                           //scope.A_method( scope.B_method ) ; 
                                           //    SUCCEEDs,
                                           //      ... if B_method is on $scope
                                           //      ... but I understand that  
                                           //      ... 'controller as ...' is better

                                           scope.A_method( ctrl.B_method  ) ; 
                                           //     SUCCEEDS, 
                                           //       ... if I include 
                                           //       ... 'controller:"B_controller"'  
                                           //       ... but that fires the 
                                           //       ... "B_controller" twice
                                         }
                              } 
                     }
                 )
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app        = "my_app"
      ng-controller = "A_controller" >

  <div ng-controller = "B_controller as B_this">
    <div b-directive>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I think this post will help you:
http://david-barreto.com/directive-inheritance-in-angularjs/
It has all what you asked for

Comment: I must say ... that seems like a very complex way of doing what should be easy to do: reference an instance of something ... ...

Comment: It seems complex however basically you just add a require parameter in your directory for your parent controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by doing 2 things, and NOT doing one thing that I had seen several times in other posts.

see [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/41u7O6dQQhy4TFcns1jK?p=preview) ...

```
//DO:
//- in html ................. use "controller as your_prop" 
//- in directive link ....... use scope.your_prop to access the controller 

//DON'T DO:
//- in directive's return ... DON'T use 'controller' or 'controller as' properties.

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module( "my_app" , [] )
        .controller( "A_controller" , 
                     function( )
                       { var myA   = this  ;
                         myA.propA = "foo" ;
                       }
                    )
        .controller( "B_controller" , 
                     function( )
                       { var myB   = this  ;
                         myB.propB = "bar" ;                      
                       } 
                   )
        .directive( "bDirective" , 
                    function()
                       { return { //controller   : "B_controller" , // !!!! DON'T NEED THIS  
                                  link : function( scope , element , atts )  
                                           { var lvs_A = scope.A_this.propA ;  
                                             var lvs_B = scope.B_this.propB ;

                                             var lvo_root    = scope.$parent         ;
                                             lvo_root.output = lvs_A + " , " + lvs_B ;
                                           }
                                } 
                       }
                   )
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app        = "my_app"
        ng-controller = "A_controller as A_this" >

    <div ng-controller = "B_controller as B_this">
      <div B_directive>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>output: {{output}}</div>
  </body>

</html>
```